# I want to create a mirror in SQL Server 2008, but the database is in the status "restoring ..."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a mirror in SQL Server 2008, and did the following:

On the principal server

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test
SET RECOVERY FULL;
GO;

BACKUP DATABASE Test
TO DISK = N'D:\Test.Bak' WITH FORMAT
GO
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = N'D:\Test.Bak'
GO

BACKUP LOG Banco
TO DISK = N'D:\TestLog.Bak' WITH FORMAT
GO
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
FROM DISK = N'D:\TestLog.Bak'
GO
```

On the mirror server:

```
USE master;
GO;
RESTORE DATABASE Teste
FROM DISK = N'D:\Test.bak'
WITH NORECOVERY,
MOVE 'Test_Data' TO
N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_Data.mdf',
MOVE 'Test_Log'
TO N'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Test_Data.ldf'
GO

USE master
GO
RESTORE LOG Test
FROM DISK = N'D:\TestLog.bak'
WITH NORECOVERY
GO
```

I can not select, users can not change, change nothing!

[image: it happens]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be attempting to access the database on the mirror machine.  You can only access it from the Principal.

If the Principal has a problem or shuts down or whatever, the mirror will become the Principal and you then use that machine to access the database.

Answer (score 1):

@MaxVernon is right, you can't access the mirrored database. Mirroring is a High Availability option, which means that it helps keep a database available in case of a problem. This is done by means of delivering transactions to the mirrored machine.

It provides cluster like technology but per database, not per machine. You can fail over from the principle db (main) to the mirror in case of any troubles, and still have the database available, with little (or no) data loss.

The mirrored database is kept in Restoring mode exactly for SQL Server to be able to apply transactions coming from the main server as soon as possible.

Now, if you need to scale out your db, or just read data from it from another place than production, you might need/use a different technology which allows the child db to stay online:

- database snapshots (available only on the same machine as the source database)

  - you can also create a snapshot on the mirror and make it available for reading
  - but need to take into consideration that snapshots are a one time picture of the source db and you might run into space issues;
- log shipping (same or different machine, allows child db to be available as read-only)
- replication (same or different machine, allows child db as read-write)

But this is a longer story to what technology to chose.